# Differential geometry problem from a special relativity exam

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

I'm having some trouble solving the following problem, could you please give me a solution? I know what covariant derivative is, but no idea about the manifold they mention and what particular tensor they're talking about: it's from an exam in relativity and it seems to use different langiages than mathematicians are normally used to: a compete solution would be great!

a) Consider a congruence of curves $x^{a}= x^{a}(u)$ defined in such way that there is only
one curve through each point of the manifold. Using this congruence, introduce
a vector field over the whole manifold. Find the Lie derivative with respect to
this vector field of the contravariant components $T^{ab}$ of the rank two tensor field $T.$

b) The covariant derivative of the contravariant component $X^{a}$ of the vector field
$X$ is given by $\nabla_{c}X^{a}= \partial_{c}X^{a} + \Gamma_{bc}^{a}X^{b}.$

and the covariant derivative of the mixed components of the rank 2 tensor field
$T$ is given by:

$$\nabla_{d}T^{a}_c = \partial_{d}T^{a}_c + \Gamma^{a}_{ed}T^{e}_c- \Gamma^{e}_{cd}T^{a}_e$$

Using the commutator of the contravariant vector field $Y^{a}$ derive the expression
for the Riemann curvature tensor.

Comment: Rather than ask for "a complete solution" to a problem whose manifold you have "no idea about," it is more beneficial to take things a step at a time.  Ask incremental questions to advance from what determines the (diferentiable) manifold structure to the ultimate goals set forth.

Comment: So, the exam doesn't say what the tensor $T$ is, what the vector field $Y$ is, or what the Riemannian metric is?  (And presumably, it also doesn't say what's meant by a "congruence of curves"?)

Comment: Nope, it says nothing!